# QWebView некоторые странички делают мне Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Добрый день!

Qt 5.4 `QWebView` со слегка изменённым `QNetworkAccessManager` роняет программу при загрузке некоторых страниц. 
Не знаю как объяснить подробнее, поэтому наваял простейший пример.

***Примечание:*** файла, на который вела находящаяся здесь ссылка, больше не существует. Однако из ответа можно попытаться восстановить общую идею проблемного участка.

Comment: Когда приложение падает, оно кидает исключение. Выясните, что за исключение Вы получаете.

Comment: И, пожалуйста, не надо создавать метки с именами классов в Qt.

Comment: Павел, объясните, а зачем Вы используете QCustomNetworkReply? Для чего Вы его ввели?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас тут получается интересная ситуация в переопределённом методе `QCustomNetworkAccessManager::createRequest()`:

1. создаёте запрос `QNetworkRequest`, получив ответ
   `QNetworkReply`;
2. ждёте, когда запрос выполнится и ответ заполнится данными, не выходя из метода создания запроса;
3. создаёте новый объект класса "кастомного" ответа `QCustomNetworkReply` и из имеющегося ответа копируете в него заголовки и полученное содержимое, причём последнее, помимо того, что `QNetworkReply` открывает собственный экземпляр `QIODevice`, переносится в отдельный `QByteArray`;
4. возвращаете полученный "кастомный ответ".

Ваш "кастомный" ответ не является точной копией реального ответа. Вы не переопределили все методы, которые обращаются с данными, ограничившись лишь `QCustomNetworkReply::readData()`. А их много, т.к. `QNetworkReply` унаследован от `QIODevice`. Поскольку Ваш "кастомный" ответ содержит, пусть и открытый, но пустой экземпляр `QIODevice`, то при вызове его любого другого непереопределённого метода будет, как говорится, undefined behavior. Вероятно, именно в этом причина сегфолта, поскольку вебстраница, которую Вы привели в качестве примера осуществляет множество подгрузок различного содержимого. Не удивительно, что на относительно статичной странице с яндексом из второго примера ошибки не случается, тогда как в первом случае происходит "вылет".

Также, Вы упустили момент, что объект класса реального ответа у Вас остаётся активен, Вы не удаляете его после создания "кастомного" ответа, а значит он будет жить, пока будет существовать объект класса `QCustomNetworkAccessManager`. Поскольку последний обычно существует на протяжении жизни всей программы, то в памяти будет бесполезно накапливаться куча реальных ответов.

Цель ввода отдельного класса "кастомного" ответа мне неизвестна, но, вероятно, Вам следует изменить подход.

Comment: Спасибо, цель проста. Мне надо изменить заголовки в передаваемом из браузера запросе. В том числе и заголовок "Accept-Encoding", а далее чудеса, оказалось что получив изменённый "Accept-Encoding" QNetworkAccessManager не распаковывает упакованные в gzip ответы. https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=63696 Приходится дожидаться ответа, распаковывать его самостоятельно и передавать уже как QCustomNetworkReply

Comment: P.S. Кстати, да, пардон, в примере забыл reply->deleteLater(); в реальной программе она есть, правда от падений не спасает :)