# QWebView and NetworkAccessManager. Завернуть все HTTP запросы в какой нибудь IPC

Tags: c++, http, qt5, ipc

Доброго времени суток.

Хочу написать простейшее клиент серверное приложение на QT.
Процессы клиента и сервера собираюсь писать на С++ и QT5
Интерфейс будет на html5+css+javascript

Клиентская часть приложения это будет простейший Web браузер который будет просто загружать web страничку следующим образом:

```
QWebView* pView = new QWebView;
pView->load(url);
```

А также будет реализован простейший веб сервер на TCP сокетах с помощью QT. Примеров реализации простейшего веб сервера на QT в Интернете тоже много. Это нужно чтобы к простейшему веб серверу можно было подключаться по сети обычным вебраузером *(Firefox, Chrome, etc...)*

Это могут быть как два отдельных *(свой браузер и свой сервер)* приложения *(отдельных процесса)*, так и два треда *(потока)* внутри одного процесса. Как лучше сделать пока еще не решил.

**Вопрос заключается в следующем:**

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы клиент *(QWebView, или QNetworkAccessManager)* мог **посылать HTTP запросы серверу не только по сети, а и напрямую** *(это именно в случае когда и клиент и сервер запущены на одном компьютере, если они будут на разных компьютерах то тут и так ясно что они смогут ТОЛЬКО по сети общаться)* **используя какой нибудь IPC.**

Ну вот например приходит в голову мысль посылать HTTP запросы серверу по DBus и получать ответ от сервера тоже по DBus, ну или может быть каким то другим способом на одном компьютере передавать HTTP запрос и получать HTTP ответ от одного процесса другому

**Тоесть как я понимаю, нужно завернуть изначально идущий сетевой HTTP запрос из сети в IPC.**

Это все дело мне нужно для того, чтобы после реализации браузера и сервера, сконцентрироваться на разработке бизнесс логики приложения уже на JavaScript, который будет соответственно посылать серверу различные AJAX запросы. И соответственно нужно чтобы все эти AJAX запросы тоже шли к серверу не по TCP *(network)* а локально по IPC, и ответы на них тоже приходили по IPC.

**Update**

Поясню зачем все именно такое нужно.

Данное приложение будет являться переносной (т.н. Portable) системой по управлению и накоплению документации. Т.е. некоторый гибрид Knowledge Tree и Wiki движка. Пересмотрел много самых разных вики движков, и переносных и самых разных. Решил писать свое, потому что в существующих не хватает нужной именно мне функциональности. Важно чтобы данную систему можно было носить с собой на флешке и смотреть с любого компа. Допустим зашел к человеку починить компьютер, у которого нет, или не доступен интернет, но нужно в своей документации посмотреть какую либо инструкцию. 
Поэтому нужно чтобы решение было кроссплатформенным и работало под Linux, Windows и Android.

Также нужно чтобы была Web версия приложения. Например нужно коллеге по работе посмотреть какую либо инструкцию, он заходит на мой сайт, и смотрит ту же самую инструкцию того же самого приложения на сайте.

Чтобы не писать два разных приложения (версия для сайта и версия переносная для десктопа), решил сразу интерфейс приложения делать на html5+css+javascript. А чтобы этот же интерфейс был переносным, решил для этого использовать QT и QWebView.

Почему решил свой простейший браузер делать?  да по той причниче что у любого браузера ограниечние для доступа к файловой системе, а мне нужно чтобы это локальное веб приложение могло сохранять документацию в формате html на файловую систему.

А теперь про то зачем мне нужно IPC.
Все дело в том, что иногда приходится работать за компьютерами, на которых у меня нет админских привилегий. Некоторые администраторы с соображений безопасности, закрывают фаерволами все лишнее. И например если запустить свое такое приложение (Portable Web сервер и Portable Browser) на таком компе, где фаерволами закрыто абсолютно все, и localhost в том числе, то фаервол может это блокировать. Отсюда и возникла мысль о том, чтобы HTTP запросы отправлять серверу не по сети, как это изначально делает QWebView через QNetworkAccessManager, а напрямую от одного процесса другому, например через DBus, или как либо еще.
Да я изначально рассматривал вариант использовать qtwebkit bridge, чтобы из JavaScript получить доступ к файловой системе сохраняя файлы на диск. Но тут тогда получается для функциональности CRUD нужно также реализовывать два варианта, один для работы по сети в случае версии приложения как сайт, и второй - для локальной версии которая будет уже делать CRUD через qtwebkit bridge.

Если завернуть HTTP коммуникацию между сервером и вьюэром через IPC, то можно будет сконцентрироваться только лишь на разработке серверной части сайта. Т.е. писать приложение как обычный сайт с клиент-серверной архитектурой приложения на HTML+CSS+JavaScript, а сервер будет использоваться только лишь для операций CRUD (Создавать, читать, редактировать, удалять) над документами. И если завернуть HTTP запросы через IPC, то тогда локальному клиент серверному Web приложению не будут мешать фаерволы, и не нужно будет делать несколько реализаций некоторой функциональности для локальной и веб версии приложения. Вот собственно говоря и все ТЗ.
И если реализовать данную задумку завернув HTTP запросы не через сеть а через IPC, то тогда вся эта глобальная задумка с множеством вышеописанных требований к приложению красиво решается.

PhantomJS тоже рассмаривал для этого. Но он не подходит потому что это просто JavaScript движок, а мне нужно еще и выполнять рендеринг HTML+CSS, плюс насколько мне известно, нет реализации под Android. QWebView Собственно говоря делает тоже самое, только оно кроссплатформенное и доступно во всех популярных платформах.

Главный вопрос:
**Как завернуть HTTP запросы от QWebView в какой нибудь IPC чтобы отправлять их локально не через сеть другому процессу?**

Второстепенный вопрос:
**В каком классе/методе/месте QNetworkAccessManager обращается к сети?**

Comment: А в чем существенное отличие локального и удаленного сервера? Зачем такое разделение требуется?

Comment: Я думаю, что вопросы типа "Напишите мне ТЗ" не должны рассматриваться.

Comment: Реализация работы браузера с пропусканием запросов через QNetworkAccessManager есть в PhantomJS. Можете посмотреть там код.

Comment: Зря вы так боитесь "сети". Абсолютно нормально все будет работать, даже со флешки и без включенного интернета, если у вас демон будет слушать по какому-нибудь порту 127.0.0.1, а в браузере вы будете туда обращаться.

Comment: Ну а если фаервол MS Windows, который фильтрует сеть даже не по портам а по приложениям? в таком случае и 127.0.0.1 т.н. локалхост пускать не будет. Поэтому вопрос все еще актуален

Comment: Ну или может кто знает в каком классе/методе/месте QNetworkAccessManager обращается к сети?

Answer (score 2):

`QWebView` использует `QWebPage`, а последний - `QNetworkAccessManager`. Унаследуйте собственный класс от `QNetworkAccessManager` и переопределите его виртуальный защищённый метод нужным функционалом:

```
QNetworkReply *QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest(Operation op
    , const QNetworkRequest &req, QIODevice *outgoingData = 0)
```

**Примечание:** устанавливайте объект наследника `QNetworkAccessManager` в `QWebPage` исключительно до первой загрузки какой-либо страницы. Также необходимо помнить, что по умолчанию `QWebPage` не становится родителем объекта `QNetworkAccessManager` при установке в него последнего.

**Дополнение:** Если требуется выполнять произвольные http(s)-запросы, то в общем случае подойдёт `QNetworkAccessManager::sendCustomRequest()`. Однако это не решит проблему при изменением логики, когда, например, вместо традиционно предполагаемой отправки данных удалённому серверу, требуется эти данные перенаправить другому процессу через `DBus`. В подобных случаях, в методе `QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest()` придётся блокировать стандартно отправляемый запрос, но при этом тут же создавать отдельное соединение через сокет (либо реализовывать иной механизм передачи данных). Поскольку метод `QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest()` не является асинхронным, это приводит к требованию о немедленном возврате указателя на объект `QNetworkReply`. Придётся создавать свой собственный объект ответа, в который, после того, как будут получены данные от произвольного источника, необходимо будет эти данные внести.

Comment: Смотрел я в коде метод:
`QNetworkReply *QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest(Operation op
    , const QNetworkRequest &req, QIODevice *outgoingData = 0)`
Вот только не пойму, где он там обращается к TCP сокетам? или может непостредственно к сети обращается класс **QNetworkReply**?

Comment: @Vitaliy , судя по Qt-исходникам, ни `QNetworkReply`, ни `QNetworkAccessManager` к сокетам непосредственно не обращаются. Это делают приватные Qt-классы. Без правки соответствующих исходников до сокета добраться не получится.

Comment: у меня совсем небольшой опыт в этом, поэтому и спрашиваю где искать. Цепочку этих классов можете подсказать чтобы понять как это работает и как `QNetworkAccessManager` обращается к сокетам?

Comment: @Vitaliy , боюсь, что структуру классов без глубокого погружения для изучения я не в состоянии описать. Там ведь в том числе и платформозависимый код используется. Вам придётся вносить изменения, учитывая и этот фактор. Ну и я не вполне понимаю, зачем Вам это, если Ваша задача заключается в том, чтобы, не дав хода определённым по умолчанию конструкциям, выполнить свою собственную. Для этого не вызывайте в переопределённом методе `QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest()` его базовое тело, и ни один веб-запрос не сработает. Просто подмените тело метода собственным решением.

Comment: реализовывая `QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest()` непонятно что делать со слотами и сигналами и кто создает объект `QNetworkReply` или как и когда получить на него ссылку. HTTP это текстовый протокол, и без разницы куда отправлять эти текстовые данные в TCP сокет или в dbus, и таким образом будут и исгналы со слотами работать, (а так прийдется сигналы со слотами писать самому) и переписывать будет немного. Создавая свой `createRequest()` прийдется пол модуля QNetwork переписывать, а так хотел переделать только место где пишется в сокет, То получится минимум переделывания

Comment: @Vitaliy , здесь на сайте (http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/424591/qwebview-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5-segmentation-fault/424636#424636) уже обсуждалась тема переопределения обозначенного метода. Там есть исходники. И как видите, QNetwork переписывать не пришлось. С некоторыми доработками вполне возможно получить искомый результат. В обратном случае придётся изучать QNetwork, реализовывать патч, пересобирать Qt.